# How to make data constantly updated without having to restart?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

In my application:

- The function `tuple_selection` takes data from the table in database and converts it into a list of cards, which is then passed to the variable `table_data`.
- Function `show_statistics` calls `open_statistics` which takes variable `table_data` with cartridges.
- Function `open_statistics` creates a window where it builds a table and passes the data from `table_data` into it.
- The program has a main window (in it the form is filled out and saved to database) and a window that opens `open_statistics` and displays this data in a table.

How to make the data in `open_statistics` constantly updated without having to constantly restart the program?

connection.py:

```
def tuple_selection():
    with connect(file_path) as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM statistics")
        records = cursor.fetchall()
        employee_tuples_list = [tuple(record) for record in records]
        return employee_tuples_list
table_data = tuple_selection()
```

interface.py:

```
def show_statistics():
    open_statistics(table_data)

def open_statistics(data):
    statistics = tk.Tk()
    statistics.geometry("950x400")
    statistics.title("Statistics")
    statistics.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    def sort_column(tree, col, reverse):
        data = [(float(tree.set(child, col)), child) for child in tree.get_children('')]
        
        data.sort(reverse=reverse)
        for index, (value, child) in enumerate(data):
            tree.move(child, '', index)
        tree.heading(col, command=lambda: sort_column(tree, col, not reverse))

    heads = ["DATE VALUE", "TIME VALUE", "TOURNAMENT NAME", "BUY-IN", "QUANTITY BUY-IN", "PLAYER COUNT", "TOURNAMENT PLACE", "GAIN"]  
    table = ttk.Treeview(statistics, show="headings")  
    table["columns"] =  heads
    for row in data:   
        table.insert('', tk.END, values=row)
    
    for header in heads:
        table.heading(header, text=header, anchor="center", command=lambda col=header: sort_column(table, col, False))
        table.column(header, anchor="center", width=100)

    scrollpane = ttk.Scrollbar(statistics, command=table.yview)
    scrollpane.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    table.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
    table.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollpane.set)
```

I've tried calling functions on a timer and calling functions inside those functions.

Comment: If you want to update the table periodically, you need to call `tuple_selection()` to get the data inside `open_statistics()` instead of passing the data via function argument and create a nested function to get the data and refresh the table.  Then use `.after()` to call that nested function periodically.

Comment: it is not clear where you are stuck or what you are trying to achieve ?   it would be helpful to reduce to this: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.after()` to call a function which refreshes the table periodically.  Note that you need to call `tuple_selection()` to fetch the data inside that function instead of passing the table data via argument of `open_statistics()`:

```py
def open_statistics():
    statistics = tk.Toplevel() # use tk.Toplevel for child window
    statistics.geometry("950x400")
    statistics.title("Statistics")
    statistics.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    def refresh_table():
        # clear current table
        table.delete(*table.get_children())
        # fetch the table data
        data = tuple_selection()
        # populate the data into the table
        for row in data:
            table.insert('', tk.END, values=row)
        # refresh table after 5000 ms (change it to whatever you want)
        table.after(5000, refresh_table)

    def sort_column(tree, col, reverse):
        data = [(float(tree.set(child, col)), child) for child in tree.get_children('')]

        data.sort(reverse=reverse)
        for index, (value, child) in enumerate(data):
            tree.move(child, '', index)
        tree.heading(col, command=lambda: sort_column(tree, col, not reverse))

    heads = ["DATE VALUE", "TIME VALUE", "TOURNAMENT NAME", "BUY-IN", "QUANTITY BUY-IN", "PLAYER COUNT", "TOURNAMENT PLACE", "GAIN"]
    table = ttk.Treeview(statistics, show="headings")
    table["columns"] =  heads

    for header in heads:
        table.heading(header, text=header, anchor="center", command=lambda col=header: sort_column(table, col, False))
        table.column(header, anchor="center", width=100)

    scrollpane = ttk.Scrollbar(statistics, command=table.yview)
    scrollpane.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
    table.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
    table.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollpane.set)

    refresh_table() # start the periodic refresh
```

Note also that it is better to use `tk.Toplevel` instead of `tk.Tk` for windows other than the root/main window.